# Filtering by a secondary value if the first value isn't present in SQL Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a form that shows addresses. Most companies also have a "Physical" and "Postal" address. The form currently has the company showing twice for each address where they have a physical and postal. I can't seem to find a way to filter the form so that it checks to see if the company has a Physical address and only displays that record and if it does not then it will display the postal address.

I had assumed it would be a where condition on the "AddressType" for if it equals "Physical" else display postal, but as of yet I have not tried something that works.

SQL Query

```
SELECT tblAddress.SupplierID, tblAddress.AddressType, tblAddress.Address, tblAddress.[Town/Suburb], tblAddress.Region, tblSuppliersAgreements.AgreementID, tblSuppliers.IsActive
FROM (tblSuppliers INNER JOIN tblAddress ON tblSuppliers.[ID] = tblAddress.[SupplierID]) 
INNER JOIN tblSuppliersAgreements ON tblSuppliers.[ID] = tblSuppliersAgreements.[SupplierID];
```

**Update 1**

Updated the Query in the builder to match a below answer but it was missing () around the first inner join which was why it was giving me the syntax error. I can't seem to now find where it is giving me the error for this time. It says it is between the following
`tblAddress.AddressType= (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tblAddress WHERE tblAddress.AddressType='Physical' and tblAddress.[SupplierID]=tblSuppliers.[ID]) THEN 'Physical' ELSE 'Postal' END)` and once I hot Okay it Highlights the `WHEN` part.

Updated Query

```
SELECT tblAddress.SupplierID, tblAddress.AddressType, tblAddress.Address, tblAddress.[Town/Suburb], tblAddress.Region, tblSuppliersAgreements.AgreementID, tblSuppliers.IsActive
FROM (tblSuppliers 
INNER JOIN tblAddress ON tblSuppliers.[ID] = tblAddress.[SupplierID]) 
INNER JOIN tblSuppliersAgreements ON tblSuppliers.[ID] = tblSuppliersAgreements.[SupplierID]
WHERE tblAddress.AddressType=
             (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                                                FROM tblAddress 
                                                WHERE tblAddress.AddressType='Physical' and tblAddress.[SupplierID]=tblSuppliers.[ID]) 
                                    THEN 'Physical'
                                    ELSE 'Postal'
                                    END)
```

Shortened but listed the above incase this contains an error

```
SELECT ta.SupplierID, ta.AddressType, ta.Address, ta.[Town/Suburb], ta.Region, tsa.AgreementID, ts.IsActive
FROM (tblSuppliers ts
INNER JOIN tblAddress ta ON ts.[ID] = ta.[SupplierID])
INNER JOIN tblSuppliersAgreements tsa ON ts.[ID] = tsa.[SupplierID]
WHERE ta.AddressType=
             (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                                FROM tblAddress
                                                WHERE AddressType='Physical' and SupplierID=ts.[ID])
                                    THEN 'Physical'
                                    ELSE 'Postal'
                                    END)
```

[image: Current Error with SQL Pictured]

Comment: What is purpose of form - data entry/edit for which table? Is this query even editable? I usually see Physical and Postal addresses as fields in Companies table. If you want an Addresses table because some addresses can be used for multiple companies, then could have foreign key fields in Companies for AddressID.

Comment: purpose of form is to display companies within certain regions. The query is the from the Query builder in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current syntax error happens because Access SQL does not support `CASE ... WHEN`.  You need a different strategy.

Sounds like your `AddressType` field contains either *"Physical"* or *"Postal"*.  And you want  the *"Physical"* row for each supplier if it exists; otherwise the *"Postal"* row.

Since *"Physical"* sorts before *"Postal"*, this query will return *"Physical"* as `preferred_address` for any supplier which includes a row with *"Physical"* in `AddressType`.

```sql
SELECT
    SupplierID,
    Min(AddressType) AS preferred_address
FROM tblAddress
GROUP BY SupplierID
```

Assuming that query identifies the supplier addresses you want, `INNER JOIN` it back to `tblAddress` to select only the matching rows.

```sql
SELECT
    adrs.SupplierID,
    adrs.AddressType,
    adrs.Address,
    adrs.[Town/Suburb],
    adrs.Region
FROM
    tblAddress AS adrs
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            SupplierID,
            Min(AddressType) AS preferred_address
        FROM tblAddress
        GROUP BY SupplierID
    ) AS sub
    ON adrs.SupplierID = sub.SupplierID AND adrs.AddressType = sub.preferred_address;
```

And assuming that still gives you only the addresses you want, adapt your original query to use this one in place of `tblAddress`.

Comment: So far this seems to be working until I try the `INNER JOIN` I get a type mismatch which I am assuming is due to `SupplierID` being a number and `AddressType` being text? I take it this happens on the last line with the `ON` section?

Comment: I did try this solution but I had not come back into comments to update yet. When doing it this way it no longer filters correctly and displays all records. Is there a way to make the the Number data type proxy as a text type or a way to circumvent the data type issue?

Comment: I had only seen the first edit when checking the update and had not seen the second part. This has solved and now I just need to add back in the other info to adapt my original query. Much appreciated!